# ASP.NET and Help file

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get some input in regard to creating a help file:

1. Prefered to have a help show up based on what active screen is.
2. Obviosuly, it can be searched
3. It can be browse
4. So it's like normal help file if you press F1 for Internet Explorer that sort of thing.

I'm appreciated your feedback

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for product references which build help files for you or some technical aspect of how to make it work?

Comment: No no ... it's like this. Let say if you have application about CRM for instace. First screen will be about Customer detail page containing fields about customer. So we would like have a button or navigation saying "Help" and if you click that it lauch the help window BUT smart enough to know which area in. Thinking to XML based help BUT not sure whther this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Help" for web applications it's just additional pages with help subject related to current page, search form, help content, etc.

Nothing special here is needed. :)

Comment: Well ... I am interested in technical how to do this. What I have seen that it loads a page suing some sort of frame with left navigation for topic and main body for content and the top bit will be the search. Obvisoually, each topic will be broken up into smaller HTML file with achor tag for each section  BUT then how about the search? How I am going to search this what sort of utility or engine to to search this?